# Saving the terminal output of scheduled background process in shell script

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I am trying to read the output of background process as

```
pwd &
```

and want to read it line by line (or store in a file). I tried to store the output in a file using `>` and `tee` but it didn't worked.

```
[anuj@localhost ~]$ ls & | tee output.txt
```

> bash: syntax error near unexpected token `|'

```
[anuj@localhost ~]$ 
[anuj@localhost ~]$ ls & > output.txt
```

using `>` it is executing the command but nothing storing in the output.txt

FYI,

Basically I want to execute multiple command from a `.sh` file but after every command's execution I want to check the output of that command (before going to next command) to decide to move next command or abort the script.

Comment: When you mean `output of that command (before going to next command)` read certain string from previous command (or) if the command runs successfully, run the next command?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should be the other way around:

```
ls > output &
```

If you do it your way you would store the output of a process in the background in the `output`-file. But in the background your command isn't going to print something on the output.

Comment: Thanks a lot Moritz for detailed explanation. It is working fine.

Comment: Would you mind accepting the answer then? Help: http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers